# SQL: Delete only one row if join returns multiple matches

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-delete

I have an SQL table that looks as follows:

```
col1   col2
a      b
b      a
c      d
d      c
f      g
```

As you can see there are rows where both columns `col1` and `col2` are inverted. What I mean is that in the first row the values `a` and `b` are in both columns and in row 2 the values are also there, but the other way round.

I now want to delete one row of each of these pairs. I do not care which side of the pair is deleted. So either row 1 and row 3 or row 2 and row 4 should be deleted.

The result should looks as follows:

```
col1   col2
a      b
c      d
f      g
```

or

```
col1   col2
b      a
d      c
f      g
```

I achieved this with the following query that creates two artificial columns that contain the values in a sorted order and then applies a `GROUP BY`, but I assume there should be a nicer looking solution.

```
DELETE t1
FROM testtable t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CASE WHEN col1 < col2 THEN col1 ELSE col2 END AS first, 
    CASE WHEN col1 < col2 THEN col2 ELSE col1 END AS second
    FROM testtable
    GROUP BY CASE WHEN col1 < col2 THEN col1 ELSE col2 END, CASE WHEN col1 < col2 THEN col2 ELSE col1 END
    ) t2 ON t2.first = t1.col1 AND t2.second = t1.col2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simplify your query by adding conditions to the join:

```
    DELETE T1
    FROM #testable T1
        INNER JOIN #testable T2 ON T1.col1 = T2.col2 AND T1.col2 = T2.col1 AND T1.col1 > T1.col2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` & `not exists`  :

```
select t.*
from testtable t 
where exists (select 1 
              from testtable t1 
              where t1.col1 > t.col1 and t1.col1 = t.col2
             ) or
      not exists (select 1 
                  from testtable t1 
                  where t1.col1 < t.col1 and t1.col1 = t.col2
                 );
```

If you want to remove unwanted records then you can do :

```
delete t
from testtable t 
where not exists (select 1 
                  from testtable t1 
                  where t1.col1 > t.col1 and t1.col1 = t.col2
                 ) and
       exists (select 1 
               from testtable t1 
               where t1.col1 < t.col1 and t1.col1 = t.col2
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no actual duplicates, I would do:

```
delete t from testtable t
    where col1 > col2 and
          exists (select 1
                  from testtable t2
                  where t2.col1 = t.col2 and t2.col2 = t.col1
                 );
```

That is, delete the rows where `col1 > col2` but only if the "paired" row already exists in the table.